# Как сделать фон в меню?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать фон для меню? если у меня вот такой стиль:

```css
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  width: 300px;
}

.menu li {
  border-top: solid 1px #505050;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #c9b5b5;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: ffffff;
  color: #2590f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>
        item1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        item2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        item3
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

и мне надо сюда вписать код для фона в мюню! а какой?

Comment: За сегодняшний день полюбил посты данного автора.

Comment: @Crasher, дык это только начало. Разминка, так сказать ))

Comment: @Deonis, я уже все вопросы перечитал. О форуме на php особо порадовал :D

Answer (score 1):

Если в качестве фона надо вставить текстуру или картинку, то нужен

```
background-image: url('images/bg.jpg')
```

(заменить путь на свой).

Comment: дак мне надо с стиль!

Comment: @d1b2 вас прекрасно поняли. понять не можете вы. сайт за вас генераторы не сделают. и люди тоже имеют ограниченное терпение. здесь людям не пишут код, а помогают научиться чему-то. у вас стремление какое-то прямо противоположное - узнать как можно меньше, при этом сделать сайт.   
Про background-image вам уже отвечали в одном из ваших "вопросов" и у вас даже получилось добавить его в стиль, вспомните как вы это сделали и повторите.

Comment: Я уже понял всё и записал в стили, а как изменить размер, просто у меня слишком большая картинка!

Comment: Теперь у меня вот такой стиль:

    <style>
    .menu {list-style:none; width:200px;}
    .menu li {border-top:solid 1px #bbbbbb; border-bottom:solid 1px #808080;}
    .menu li a {text-decoration:none;padding:5px 10px ; display:block; color:#bbbbbb;}
    .menu li a:hover {background:#5f7696; color:#bbbbbb;}
    .menu {background-image: url('/images/fon.png');}
    </style>

Comment: В фотошопе изменяешь размер изображения.